# Display WP Start bar on front page only

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, conditional-content

I was wondering if someone could help me display the plugin [WP Start bar](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-start-bar/) only on my static frontpage. If it helps my static frontpage url is: http://zackarylundquist.westhostsite.com/portfolio/

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the plugin's source, its main bits are hooked as following:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'init_wpstartbar_files');
add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'init_wpstartbar_admin');
add_action('wp_footer', 'wpstartbar_footer',1);
```

The easiest way to conditionally disable it would probably be along (not tested):

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {

if( ! is_front_page() ) {
    remove_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'init_wpstartbar_files');
    remove_action('admin_print_scripts', 'init_wpstartbar_admin');
    remove_action('wp_footer', 'wpstartbar_footer',1);
}

} );
```